# Importing 2007 files in SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, import

Good Day,

Today i am facing this error upon importing an excel file to a databe in sql server 2008

[image]

i do not know what causes this error,  i do not know if it is because the excel file is 48MB in size, or because there is a sheet where in there are 113956 rows? if so can you help me find a work around to this? i really need to import the data inside my excel file to the database. i tried selecting the 2007 version of my excel file in the dropdown box like below but it still outputs the same problem. so any help?

Thank You.

Comment: I will suggest to check the data and its data type in excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Re saving the file but not in a CSV format, i have found out that the excel file is read only although its properties are not set to read-only, upon resaving the excel file to another file the import now works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can try:

1. Resave the Excel file as a delimited text file - that way you can get around the MS Office driver.
2. Try cutting the Excel file in half by saving it in two different files.

Out of curiosity, how many columns does this Excel file have?  I believe there is a 255 column limit.

Comment: i only have 20 columns max.